# Spark scala: convert Iterator[char] to RDD[String]

Tags: apache-spark

I am reading data from a file and have reached to a point where the datatype is Iterator[char]. Is there a way to transform Iterator[char] to RDD[String]? which then I can transform to Dataframe/Dataset using case class.

Below is the code:

```
val fileDir = "inputFileName"
val result = IOUtils.toByteArray(new FileInputStream (new File(fileDir)))
val remove_comp = result.grouped(171).map{arr => arr.update(2, 32);arr}.flatMap{arr => arr.update(3, 32); arr}
val convert_char = remove_comp.map( _.toChar)
```

This return convert_char: Iterator[Char] = non-empty iterator

Thanks

Comment: What are you really trying to achieve? If you want to read a file just `spark.read.text` or similar.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you are trying to do, but this should answer your question:

```
val ic: Iterator[Char] = ???
val spark : SparkSession = ???

val rdd: RDD[String] = spark.sparkContext.parallelize(ic.map(_.toString).toSeq)
```

Comment: I wanted to read a file blanking 2nd and 3rd bytes and then start processing.